# Class variables and a function from header are ignored by some functions while compiling

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have to write a class, but I get errors that don't make much sense to me. [Link to my codes and the error message I'm getting.](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1_TckMHO_-Wa1gteHVQYXFGcVk&usp=sharing)

I have declared private variables and functions in the header file, but a variable can't be seen by some functions and one of the functions can't be seen in the .cpp.

Precisely: `int sizeCounter` can't be seen by `void transportValues()` and `void putValue()`, but can be seen by `void size()`, `void isEmpty()` and `void enqueue()`. Also `void swapValues()` gives the "identifier not found"
error even though it is declared in the header.

What I've tried and didn't work:
Moving `sizeCounter` or `swapValues` from private to public.
Moving functions that can's see `sizeCounter` or `swapValues` from private to public.
Asking some experienced people to help.

What I've tried and did work:
Creating function prototype for `swapValues` in the .cpp.
Moving `swapValues` above `putValue` in the .cpp(this worked even if I removed the declaration from the header).

What I haven't tried:
Asking someone to compile the code to show if the error is caused by my compiler.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, BTW. OS: Win 7(x64).

If you find any other mistakes in the code not related to this ones consider no need correct me on those.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the code in the question, otherwise when the link dies the question becomes useless for others. If theres "too much code" to put in the question then reduce it to a minimal sample. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

For out-of-class definition, you should add class name before identifier, use

```
void HeapPriorityQueue::putValue(string value, string* arr)
```

rather than

```
void putValue(string value, string* arr)
```